# My cinnamon desktop environment on Ubuntu uninstalls itself randomly?

Tags: apt, python, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I was running ubuntu with cinnamon desktop environment.
This problem started yesterday after I installed python3. I uninstalled python by using the command sudo apt remove python too.
My cinnamon desktop uninstalled itself after this. Since then I have reinstalled python, python3 and the cinnamon desktop but it keeps randomly uninstalling and after a shutdown. I keep coming back to the original ubuntu desktop environment.
Also in the cinnamon desktop environment, when it runs, I cannot access the drives from Computer after accessing them once. When I try double clicking second time, nothing happens.

Comment: What OS/release are you running? Many tools rely on `python` (version can vary on release and we don't know yours) as do some packages, do if you removed something that is required by certain packages, removing the tool also causes all packages that need it to be removed too.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 with cinnamon desktop from ppa/embrosyn.